# About trace of inverse of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $\operatorname{tr} \left( {B_1^{ - 1}} \right) > \operatorname{tr} \left( {B_2^{ - 1}} \right)$,can I get $\operatorname{tr} \left( {{{\left( {A + {B_1}} \right)}^{ - 1}}} \right) > \operatorname{tr} \left( {{{\left( {A + {B_2}} \right)}^{ - 1}}} \right)$?
$A,{B_1},{B_2}$ are positive semidefinite matrices.
Thanks in advance!